# Spring Batch AsyncItemProcessor not processing in parallel

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I have a AsyncItemProcessor which I want to run in parallel with the following config. But, the processing is not happening in parallel.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAsync
public class JobConfig {
   @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilder;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("writer")
    private ItemWriter writer;

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public ItemProcessor itemProcessor() {
        ItemProcessor itemProcessor = new ItemProcessor();
        return itemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public AsyncItemProcessor asyncItemProcessor() throws IOException {
        AsyncItemProcessor asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(itemProcessor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(getAsyncExecutor());
        asyncItemProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor() {
            @Override
            protected void doExecute(Runnable task) {
                final JobExecution jobExecution = JobSynchronizationManager.getContext().getJobExecution();
                super.doExecute(() -> {
                    JobSynchronizationManager.register(jobExecution);
                    try {
                        task.run();
                    } finally {
                        JobSynchronizationManager.close();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("processing 1-");
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(100);
        return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    }

  

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public AsyncItemWriter asyncItemWriter() throws IOException {
        AsyncItemWriter asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(writer);
        asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Result> requestFileReader() {
        DefaultLineMapper lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper();  
        ......
        FlatFileItemReader<Result> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        return itemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step simpleFileStep() throws IOException {
        return stepBuilder.get("simpleFileStep").chunk(100).reader(fileReader).processor(asyncItemProcessor())
                .writer(asyncItemWriter()).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "customExecutionContext")
    @JobScope
    public ExecutionContext customExecutionContext() {
        ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
        return executionContext;
    }
}
```

The Processor Class :

```
@JobScope
public class RequestProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Result, List<Item>> {
    @Value("#{jobExecution}")
    private JobExecution jobExecution;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customExecutionContext")
    private ExecutionContext storedContext;

    @Override
    public List<Item> process(Result result) throws Exception {
             Date start = new Date();
             // Processing logic
             Date end = new Date();
            long diff = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
            log.info("Time taken to process the 
                          items:"+TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            return items;  
    }
}
```

I want to process File with 1000 records in parallel in this scenario, but only 100 items are getting processed at a time and writing at a time.
Please let me know if there is some issue with config.

Also after processing each chunk of 100 items, I am having a delay of 2 minutes before processing next chunk. In that time, I can see only following logs:

```
[GC concurrent-string-deduplication, 16.2K->0.0B(16.2K), avg 88.7%, 0.0000820 secs]
[GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 687M->302M(768M), 0.0138859 secs]
```

Comment: I added an answer to your question. I'm still curious though to know the purpose of overriding `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor#doExecute` and wrapping the task execution with `JobSynchronizationManager.register` and `JobSynchronizationManager.close`.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, Initially I didn't add this change. But there is exception happening **Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.itemProcessor': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope**. I was looking for the fix and found the following possible fix. [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1335). That's the reason I did the change with JobSynchronizationManager

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, sorry other thing I forgot to mention is that our version of Spring batch is old. So, I copied the implementation of AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter manually into our project.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency is different than parallelism. The `AsyncItemProcessor` is designed to work hand in hand with the `AsyncItemWriter` to process items concurrently. In your case, a single chunk of 100 items will be processed concurrently, but chunks will not be processed in parallel. It is still a serial execution of chunks, but every chunk is processed concurrently by different threads from the task executor.

There is no way to process chunks in parallel in Spring Batch. What Spring Batch provides though is partitioning, where partitions can be processed in parallel (either with local threads, or with remote JVMs).

So what you can do is partition your input (for example with 1000 items in each partition) and configure a partitioned step to process partitions in parallel. Note that each partition can further process chunks concurrently as well. You can find more details and a code example in the reference documentation here: [Scaling and Parallel Processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning).

Comment: Yes understand. Sorry I asked the question wrong. I understand that the 100 items need to be processed concurrently. But its not happening in my case. Or lets say there is a huge delay. I added logs at beginning of the processor and end of process method.  If I made chuck to 1, the total time to process 100 items is taking 10 minutes. But when I process chunk in AsyncItemProcessor, the end log of each process is printing after 10 minutes. That means every item in processor is sitting 10 minutes in processor.

Comment: If the chunk-size = 1, there is no point of using the asynchronous approach, you will have the same result a synchronous execution.

Comment: Initially I made chunk-size=1. But later, I found out about Async processing and changed logic to chuck size 100. But as I mentioned the processing speed is same. Also, what I thought is that if chunk size is 1(before Async), if processor is taking 10 seconds to process item, with Async and chunk of 100 being processed concurrently, I expect each processor to finish in around 10 seconds. But it’s taking 1000 seconds for each processor. Also after each chunk, before moving to new chunk, there is a 1 minute delay and GC pause happening

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: okay, I will explain the scenario. I have file with 10k records which I want to process with Spring batch. The previous dev in our company did the change to process 1 line at a time. That means it will process 1 line from csv at a time, process and write (to Kafka topic). It was taking around 3 hours for the batch job to complete. I made a change where I made chunk to 100 and then added AsyncProcessing, its still taking around 3 hours after that. I want to reduce the processing time.

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud, I updated the question with more code.

Comment: I cannot see why the processing time is the same from what you shared. I think a multi-threaded step or a partitioned step is better suited to your case than an async processor/writer.